# How to Plot General Form of a Linear Regression

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot, sagetex, mathcha

I attempted to use both Mathcha which is an online website that assists in constructing topological diagrams and plots and I also tried to use Sage, in order to plot this linear regression figure presented below but all my attempts did not result in this figure below:

[image]

Comment: do you mean you want to sketch the diagram to give the general idea of linear regression (you could draw that easily in picture mode or tikz or anything) or do you mean you want to plot the actual best fit line for a given set of data points, calculating its parameters in tex?

Comment: Hello! What I meant is how to sketch the diagram presented above. I tried using Mathcha to plot this diagram but the figure was completely awful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this, with pgfplots:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}    
\usepackage {pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\def\func(#1){0.75*#1+0.58}  % Linear regression function
\pgfmathsetmacro\y{\func(2)} % \alpha x_1 + \beta

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round, mark options={mark size=1.5pt,fill=white}]
  \begin{axis}
    [
      xmin=0,
      xmax=4,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=4,
      domain=0.25:3.75,
      axis lines=center,
      xlabel=$x$,
      ylabel=$y$,      
      xtick={2},
      xticklabels={$x_1$},
      ytick=\empty
    ]
    \addplot [thick, blue]             {(\func(x))};
    \addplot [dashed, red] coordinates {(2,0) (2,2.44)};
    \addplot [mark=*, red] coordinates {(2,\y)};
    \addplot [only marks]  coordinates {(0.5,0.80) (1,1.57)   (1.5,1.34)
                                        (2,2.44)   (2.5,2.48) (3,2.66)
                                        (3.5,3.17)};
    \node       at (2,2.44) [left]  {$y_1$};
    \node[red]  at (2,\y)   [right] {$\alpha x_1+\beta$};
    \node[blue] at (2.6,3.1)        {$y=\alpha x+\beta$};
  \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And you'll get the following figure:
[image]

Comment: Should the drawn best-fit line divide the not-on-the-line data points into two groups, each group consists of the same number of points?

Comment: @MakeMeSmarterEveryDay, I don't sure about that, but the OP asked for a sketch (in a comment) so the regression line is drawn 'by hand' and probably not realistic.

Comment: OK. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Late but here a TIKZ only attempt:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \pgfsetplotmarksize{0.4ex}

        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[xshift=0.25cm]{$x$};
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,4) node[xshift=0.25cm]{$y$};
        \draw[-,blue] (0.5,0.5) -- (3.5,3.5);
        
        \foreach \b  in {1,1.5,...,3}{
        \node[black] at (\b+rnd-rnd,\b+rnd-rnd){\pgfuseplotmark{o}};
        \b
        }
    
        \node[inner sep=0,black, label={[below, yshift=-0.2cm]$x_1$}] (n1)at (2,0){};
        \node[inner sep=0,black, label={[above]$y_1$}](n2) at (2,2.5){\pgfuseplotmark{o}};
        \path[draw,dashed,red] (n1)--(n2);
        \node[red,fill=white,inner sep=0.35ex, label={[right,xshift=0.2cm]$\alpha x_1+\beta$}] at (2,2){\pgfuseplotmark{o}};
        \node[inner sep=0,blue] (n1)at (1.5,3.5){$y=\alpha x_1+\beta$};     
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]